How to connect multiple Wifi Cards using PCIe expansion boards to RPI5?
I have multiple Intel 5300 Wifi cards with mini PCIe - Link
I have a RPI5 from which I want to connect these multiple Wifi Cards to get the CSI data from multiple Wifi cards
I was able to find these Mini PCIe HAT for RPI5 which has 1 mini PCIe slot
Link1
Link2
Can I use a PCIe extender such as this to connect the multiple Wifi Cards to get CSI data - Link
The wifi cards connected to the RPI5 will only be used to collect CSI data (no internet data transfer) from a router or another wifi card. Also for supporting power to the 4 wifi cards we would be using external power supply to the PCIe expansion card.

I was wrong with the choice of my words. How wifi csi works is we have a csi enabled wifi card example intel 5300. from the card we will ping a router and in the response signal the card would capture the CSI. There will not be data transfer it wont be used for internet connection and data transfers. ( I have edited the question, thanks for pointing it out )
